# Flutter iOS Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, crashlytics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oum4H.png)Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer' to expected
argument type 'UnsafePointer<pb_byte_t>?' (aka 'Optional<UnsafePointer>')
/Users/nex3012/Dev/flutterProjects/Fudosan/fudosan-calendar-application/ios/Pods/FirebaseS
essions/FirebaseSessions/Sources/SessionStartEvent.swift:191:55

I tried to add firebase_crashlytics in my flutter project. it throws error in iOS when compiling.

Failed to build iOS app
Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer' to expected
argument type 'UnsafePointer<pb_byte_t>?' (aka 'Optional<UnsafePointer>')
/Users/nex3012/Dev/flutterProjects/Fudosan/fudosan-calendar-application/ios/Pods/FirebaseS
essions/FirebaseSessions/Sources/SessionStartEvent.swift:191:55

Comment: have you tried to update ios pods & flutter packages?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by finding the issue in the Swift dependency and changing the offending line from:

`let bytes = (transportBytes as NSData).bytes`

TO

`let bytes = (transportBytes as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: pb_byte_t.self, capacity: transportBytes.count)`

Comment: This works, but it's _really_ dirty editing the dependency files. I guess this is a fix the dependency author needs to make? Any idea what caused this error to occur all of a sudden?

Comment: No idea what caused it and you're right -- its not a great solution and I think it needs to be fixed by the Firebase team